# Definition of the set of independent r.v. with second moment contstraint

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, notation, definition

I am trying to nice write the definition of the following set.

Def: The set of all distributing of the pair  $(X_1,X_2)$ such that

1. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent
2. Have second moment constraint $E_{F(X_1)}[X_1^2] \le 1$, $E_{F(X_2)}[X_2^2] \le 1$

I thought of the following:
\begin{align*}
S_1&=\left\{F(X_1,X_2)\Big| F(X_1,X_2)=F(X_1)F(X_2) \text{ and }  E_{F(X_1)}[X_1^2] \le 1, \ E_{F(X_2)}[X_2^2] \le 1 \right\}\\
S_2&=\left\{(F(X_1),F(X_2) )\Big| F(X_1,X_2)=F(X_1)F(X_2) \text{ and }  E[X_1^2] \le 1, \ E[X_2^2] \le 1 \right\}
\end{align*}

Which on is more correct $S_1$ or $S_2$? Also, should I write  $E_{F(X_1)}[X_1^2]$ or  $E_{F(X_1,X_2)}[X_1^2]$ or it doesn't really matter?
Thanks you for any help and comments.

Comment: The notation $E_{F(X)}[X]$ is uncommon and in my opinion you should avoid it. When you write $E[X_1^2]$ it is clear what you mean, so no need to confuse it.

Comment: But otherwise it is correct, right?

Comment: In matters of notation, you cannot say if something is correct or wrong. Either it is useful or it is not.

Comment: @Stef  I add an alternative definition. Which one would you say is more useful or correct? Thanks.

Comment: In $S_1$ it is more clear what you mean. But write $E$ without index as in $S_2$. So a combination of both is what I prefer (personal opinion) :)

Comment: @Stef do you think that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are equivalent? For some reason I fill that they are different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19185/discussion-between-stef-and-boby).

Answer (score 1):

This is the set $S$ of product distributions whose marginals both have second moment at most $1$. $$S=\left\{\mu\otimes\nu\in\mathcal M_1^+(\mathbb R)\times\mathcal M_1^+(\mathbb R)\,\left|\,\int_\mathbb R x^2\mathrm d\mu(x)\leqslant1,\,\int_\mathbb R x^2\mathrm d\nu(x)\leqslant1\right.\right\}$$

Comment: Thanks but how would you write it in terms of set notation.  Which one do you think is more correct $S_1$ or $S_2$

Comment: None of them is correct. I would not write the definition "in terms of set notation" but in plain English, as I did here. Why do you insist on writing this "in terms of set notation"?

Comment: I am setting up an optimization problem over two independent random variables with second moment constraint and I am trying to show that that set is compact. But I need definition of the set to show that it is compact.

Comment: Then define it as *the set of product distributions whose marginals both have second moment at most 1.*

Comment: So like what I did with $S_2$??

Comment: Did you read the first part of my first comment?

Comment: yes, sorry. So, the way you have it the answer is what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, if I am asking a lot of question. This is very tricky for my level. If you could give me more details why $S_1$ and $S_2$ are wrong defintions. Also, are $\mu=F_{X_1}$ and $v=F_{X_2}$ ? And what is $\mathcal{M}_1$

Comment: The set $\mathcal M_1^+(\mathbb R)$ is the set of probability measures on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$. The rest of your comments does not make a lot of sense to me, sorry. "the answer is what you mean?" Well, YES (amazing, eh?).

Comment: I will try to be more clear. Do you mind if I ask a few more questions? In your definition, is it implied that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent?

Comment: Let me play this game too: what is $\mu\otimes\nu$ to you? Can you link this measure to an independence hypothesis?

Comment: is it a cross product? Sorry, I don't know much of real analysis? I am not aware of independence hypothesis

Comment: Is it a product measure?

Comment: @Boby: do you want to show that a set of random variables is compact, or that a set of distributions is?

Comment: @Ilya I want to show that the set of distributions is compact.

Comment: @Boby: in which topology?

Comment: Dear Did and @Ilya thank you for all your help. I understand that I didn't give enough context. I restated this question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053360/is-set-of-product-distributions-compact-under-second-moment-constrains Please do not treat it as duplicate I really tried to put as much as I could to make it more general.