# Set of product distribution is the cross product of its sections

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $(X_1,X_2)$ be an independent random pair with distribution $F(X_1,X_2)$. Let
\begin{align*}
S&=\left\{F(X_1,X_2)\Big| F(X_1,X_2)=F(X_1)F(X_2) \text{ and }  E[X_1^2] \le 1, \ E[X_2^2] \le 1 \right\}\\
S_1&=\left\{F(X_1)\Big|  E[X_1^2] \le 1\right\}\\
S_2&=\left\{F(X_2)\Big|  E[X_2^2] \le 1\right\}\\
\end{align*}
we refer to $S_1,S_2$ as sections. 
What is the relationship between $S$ and $S_1,S_2$?
Is the following true
\begin{align*}
S=S_1 \times S_2
\end{align*}

Comment: do you mean the Cartesian product?

Comment: The formula for $S$ in the accepted answer being (probably adequate in a group theory context but) squarely offtopic in the probability context of the question, I would be curious to know how it satisfied the OP. Note that the question is nearly duplicated at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1051716/.

Comment: @Did, I gave two expressions for $S$, both of which are perfectly fine.

Comment: @charlotte "The relationship could be expressed as..." No it could not. "In group theory, you could express that as S1S2, but I don't know if that would be okay in this context." Indeed this is not group theory and the suggestion is not "okay in this context".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. $S_1\times S_2$ would be the set of ordered pairs
$$\{(F(X_1), F(X_2))|E[X_1^2]\leq1, E[X_2^2]\leq 1\}$$
The relationship could be expressed as
$$S=\{F(X_1,X_2)|F(X_1,X_2)=s_1s_2;s_1\in S_1, S_2\in S_2\}$$

Comment: Thank you.  You see I am trying to show that $S$ is compact. I already showed that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are compact and want to use it to show that $S$ is compact.

Comment: Then create a new question asking that. Or edit this one so that it asks that.

Comment: I will. I just wanted to give you more information. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to click the green check mark beside this answer so that people can tell the question has been answered.

Comment: @charlotte This does not answer the question. Yes I know, the OP *accepted* this answer but please do not get me started on this topic...

Comment: In what way does it not answer the question?

Comment: In the basest way: because it does not provide a "relationship between S and S1,S2" (the only one written in the answer being plain false).

Comment: Actually providing a correct answer is a lot more useful than complaining about an incorrect one. And actually pointing out specifically why an answer is false is a lot more useful than just stating that it is.

Comment: I did (point out specifically why the answer is false) and I did (provide an answer to this question on one of its near duplicates this user is posting on the site). Say, this requires a dose of chutzpah to post an answer while being ignorant of the subject, and then to complain that others signal this answer as rubbish, wouldn't you say? I wonder why you deleted "In group theory, you could express that as S1S2, but I don't know if that would be okay in this context.", which was priceless. (But next time, please use @.)