# Is set of product distributions compact under second moment constrains?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Please do not treat this question as duplicate of  [Definition of the set of independent r.v. with second moment contstraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051716/definition-of-the-set-of-independent-r-v-with-second-moment-contstraint)   which I didn't want to edit because of many useful comments. Also, in this question I try to clarify the context of the problem and what I know.

I am working on optimizing the following problem
\begin{align*}
\sup G(F_{X_1},F_{X_2})
\end{align*}
where $F_{X_1},F_{X_2}$ are distribution functions of random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. Here $G$ is a given functional that produces a number with input $F_{X_1},F_{X_2}$.

And where the suprimum is taken over all $F_{X_1},F_{X_2}$ such that  $X_1$, $X_2$ are independent, or $F_{X_1,X_2}$ is a product distribution, and have second moment constraints $E[X_1^2] \le 1$, $E[X_2^2] \le 1$. Lets refer to this set as $S$.

First, thing I want to do is to show whether the set over which I am optimizing  is compact.

However, I had some difficulties with even properly defining a set, see  [Definition of the set of independent r.v. with second moment contstraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051716/definition-of-the-set-of-independent-r-v-with-second-moment-contstraint).

**What I know**

I know that sets of the form
\begin{align*}
S_1&=\{F_{X_1}: E[X_1^2] \le 1\}\\
S_2&=\{F_{X_2}: E[X_2^2] \le 1\}
\end{align*}
are compact. The proof uses **tightness** argument which I am still learning.

I wanted to use that $S_1,S_2$ are compact to prove that $S$ is compact. I thought that $S=S_1 \times S_2$ and cartesian product of compact sets is compact.  However, again I was not able to establish the relationship between $S$ and $S_1,S_2$ and I asked this question [Set of product distribution is the cross product of its sections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051981/set-of-product-distribution-is-the-cross-product-of-its-sections).

So to put it clearly my questions are:

1. What is the set definition of $S$ in terms of $F_{X_1},F_{X_1}$
2. Does compactness of $S$ imply compactness of $S_1$ and $S_2$?
3. If 2 is NO. Can we show that $S$ is compact or not in some other way.

   I understand that the question uses a lot tools from real analysis. Please treat me as a beginner in this subject. Also, if you could provide some reference that would be great.  Thank you very much any help in advance.

**Extra:**

The norm I would like to work with is $||f||=\sup_{x}|f(x)|$.

Comment: Question 1. is entirely answered in your previous question. Questions 2. and 3. are what prevents this from being a duplicate. Unfortunately, 2. and 3. are no real questions unless you make precise the topology you put on your spaces (as was already mentioned to you). (Say, why are you mixing things on purpose like that?)

Comment: I will get back to u on topology. What do u mean when u say I am mixing things?

Comment: Questions already answered and new ones.

Comment: I wanted to give more context. I hoped that this would clarify what I wanted. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Did I have done a little bit of reading and it seems to me that the norm I have to works with is $||f||=\sup_{x}|f(x)|$.  Does the question make more sense now. If not, could point me to some more reading? Thanks.